# Lighttpd rewrite - if folder / file exists then load, else

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

In Lighttpd, how would I express:

"if folder or file exists then navigate to it, else do rewrite rules below"

In Apache this worked well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a mechanism like that in lighttpd. You can only check if a file *doesn't* exist. That means whatever rules you have after:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Will need to go into a block like this:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (


)
```

edit: added equals sign

Because if the mod_rewrite rules that you have in your question doesn't get executed (which stops rewriting if the request is for a file/directory that exists), that means the request is for a file/directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, that actually seems more logical than the .htaccess method